# Laravel 4, I defined a route but error message still says [route] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-4, custom-routes

I defined a route in Laravel as:

```
/*Create Commission (POST)*/
Route::post('/commissions/create', array(
  'as'    => 'commission-create-post',
  'uses'  => 'CommissionController@postCreate',
));
```

But am getting error message: `Route [commission-create-post] not defined.` Also when I look up the routes using `php artisan routes` in Command Prompt it is not showing up.

I have used similar code for other routes but do not understand why this is not working.  Any and all help understanding where I went wrong or how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so very much!

---

**Edit**

Here is the link in the Nav:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('commission-create') }}">A Commission</a></li>
```

Here is the function in the CommissionController

```
public function getCreate(){
        return View::make('commissions.create');
    }
```

It leads to a form for creating a commission. The form will display only if I remove the
`commission-create-post` part of

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'commission-create-post', 'name' => 'commission_form', 'id' => 'commission_form')) }}
```

If I don't I get the error message saying that route is not defined despite clearly being defined in my routes file.

Comment: can you include a few surrounding code? it should be a problem somewhere else. or dashes are not allowed as a route name? I don't know too.

Comment: All other routes are working fine?

Comment: Yes. That is the only one that seems to not be working. Also the only one that is not showing up in command prompt.

Comment: Long shot, maybe something with caching? php artisan cache:clear..

Comment: Do you have any duplicate route names?

Comment: @gv0029 how about trying to rename the route with something simpler for test.

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have URL::route('commission-create') because the route method accepts the route name, so it should be URL::route('commission-create-post') as seen here http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Edit: Now I see where my mistake is, that link is referring to another route, I'll continue checking your problem now.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'method' => 'POST' to your form open method to make sure? Try 'method' => 'PUT'

Comment: You're not using `Route::controller` anywhere?

Comment: Good idea intelis, but it didn't fix the problem. Thanks though.

Comment: Deleted the route, copy and pasted it and it worked. No clue whats going on lol. Oh well. It's working now. Thanks for helping to everyone though.